# How to determine whether extensions have been made to JRules that won't be automatically converted to ODM?

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I am facing an upgrade of the JRules 7.112 portion of our application to ODM 8.5.  Unfortunately, the people who did the JRules work are no longer around, and we lack much in-house expertise.

[Migrating from JRules to ODM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21589725#modelExtensions) lists the steps that need to done to upgrade.  Apparently, there are several scripts to assist in upgrading to ODM, but several things must be done manually.  Migrating rule model extensions and extension data are among these.  Is it sufficient to search for *.brmx files and *.brdx files to determine whether these extensions were done?  Other words of wisdom (e.g., regarding incompatibilities, "gotchas") regarding the migration process are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to where you have installed ODM 8.5, you will find a directory called "teamserver/bin".

In here you will then find two files, "defaultExtension.brdx" and "defaultExtension.brmx".

Make a copy of these files, then open them up and compare the contents with your JRules 7.1 versions to see if there are any differences.

Once you have got these upto date, then you can upload them to your ODM 8.5 Decision Server database by going through the Installation Wizard (Configure->Installation Settings Wizard) when you set up your new ODM 8.5 Decision Centre database.

You need to do all this before you migrate the old 7.1 database to 8.5 as it expects the new target ODM 8.5 database to be there when you run the migration Ant task.

If you need any more help on this, just let me know.